# How to translate .PDF files using google APIs?

Tags: php, javascript, pdf, translation, google-translate

How to translate `.PDF` files using google APIs? (translate from language the pdf's are to for example russian (new pdf file orplain text or html).) (code example needed)

Comment: Translate to what? Images? Text? Html? You should be more specific.

Comment: I think he wants to translate a PDF to a different language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could link the PDFs to
http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=fr&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://www.example.com/PDF.pdf

The query paramaters:

hl: original language
tl: language to translate to
u: URL for PDF

If you would like to use the AJAX API I guess you first need to extract the text content from the PDF with some PHP and then translate it with [Googles AJAX API for translation](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/).

Comment: Is it possible to make google autodetect in what language is original PDF document? (so to be able to translate from any language to one you need)

Comment: Sure, just don't use the hl-parameter and it will automatically detect the language. So like this:

    http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://www.example.com/PDF.pdf